# Jasper Reports does not find correctly the pages in TOC (table of contents) when there are duplicate titles

Tags: jasper-reports

I hope you are very well.

Currently I am developing a report be means of *Jasper Reports* and *Java*, for doing it I am using two **groups**, to group the elements of the data source.

DataSoruce returned by the database has the follows structure (it has two columns):

> **Group 1**         **|**              *SubGroup A*
>
> **Group 2**         **|**              *SubGroup A*

I am showing the result in the jasper file with the follows way:

```
->Group 1

    SubGroup A

->Group 2

    SubGroup A
```

Like you can see, there are two groups: **Group 1** and **2**, and each group has a subgroup, for this example is the same subgroup (*SubGroup A*).

Every groups were configurated for appearing in the Toc (table of contents report). I used **iReport tool**, and configured each group to has a **Hiperlink** and a **Bookmark Level**.  (Groups with 1 Bookmark level and SubGroups with 2 Bookmark level).

Every works fine, the TOC appears correctly and when I select one element in TOC index, the document arrived me to correspondent page, however there is a problem, when the name of Group, or SubGrups, is the same each other (it has already appeared in the TOC, its name is duplicated), the Pdf file does not arrived correct page, takes me to the first page they have that title.

Does someone know how can I solve this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What anchor name expressions are you using for the anchor elements?  Are the values produced by the expressions unique across the report?

Comment: Hi dada67. The expression is the group name, and it is duplicated.

Comment: The anchor names need to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

1.- I created an variable RANDOM with the expression:

```
new Random().nextInt(1000)
```

2.- In the **Anchor Name Expression** I have called the variable RANDOM and behind it I wrote an *.

```
$F{TITLE} + "* " + $V{RANDOM}
```

3.- In the TOC report I added the follows expression each $F{label}, like this:

```
 ( $F{label}.contains("*") ?    $F{label}.substring( 0, $F{label}.indexOf("*" ))  :    $F{label}  )
```

And it is all, each title will be a unique name and the index will have the link correct for each page.